# Why do some of profiles say I have not participated in any tags yet?

Tags: support, bug, profile-page, top-tags

I took a look at my profiles and found that my profiles at [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70898/nobody?tab=profile) and [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99448/nobody?tab=profile) both say that I have not participated in any tags yet, although I do have answers with upvotes on both of these sites.
[image: Screenshot of my profile at codegolf]

Looking around, I found plenty of [other](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/12675/user1049697) [users](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/129883/fire-quacker) whose profiles' have the same problem. On the other hand, my profile at StackOverflow *does* show top tags (although I only have zero score questions/answers there). Is this a bug, or is there some other documented reason that I can't seem to find with a google search?